# Installing applications off Msata SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have Windows 7 running on a 32GB Msata SSD.
I have tons of games to install, (Dota2, GTA , NBA, etc), and definitely the SSD is not large enough for all these things.

If I install these applications off the default folder (C:\Program Files)
when I run it does the performance take a toll because it's not running from the SSD?

Can I move Windows folders like (Users, My Documents, etc.) off the SSD? Games like NBA save certain files over these folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is if I install these applications off the default
>   folder (C:\Program Files) when I run it does the performance take a
>   toll because its not running from the SSD?

The performance loss would be that your not using your SSD storage device for these files beyond that there wouldn't be a performance loss.

> And can i move windows folders like (Users , My Documents etc) off the
>   SSD Drive? Games like NBA save certain files over these folders.

### How to Create A Restore Point

> 1. Open System by clicking the Start button, right-clicking Computer,
>      and then clicking Properties.
> 2. In the left pane, click System protection. If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>      provide confirmation.
> 3. Click the System Protection tab, and then click Create.
> 4. In the System Protection dialog box, type a description, and then click Create.

### Go to System Recovery/Command Prompt:

> 1. Boot with the Win7 Install DVD, choose language, currency and keyboard, and hit Next.
>
>    2. At the screen with the "Install Now" choose "Repair your computer"
>    3. You will be asked if you want to "Repair and Restart" by the System Recovery options, choose "No".
>    4. Then Make sure that Windows 7 is listed as one of the installed OS's available for recovery, and that it's selected and then press
>         next. You will be given a list of recovery tools.
>    5. Choose "Command Prompt".
>
> Find your virtual Windows drive loaded from the Win7 media (probably
>   either C or X), find your actual Windows/SSD drive (D or E) and find
>   your HDD (regular hard drive) (D or E).
>
> Some report that System Recovery mode will set up their drives like
>   this: C: virtual/temp Windows drive D: Actual Windows/SSD drive E:
>   HDD, they want to put \Users on.
>
> In the command prompt you will be using Robocopy (NOT xcopy!) to copy
>   c:\Users to d:\Users, then delete the old c:\Users, then make a
>   symlink from c:\Users to D:\Users. Note that you must do these things
>   in order, and you must not have a d:\Users dir before you do this.
>   NOTE: in the System Recovery command prompt window, your drives are
>   not the same as they will be after you leave recovery mode! So adjust
>   the commands below for how the drives are in Recovery Mode, and then
>   they'll turn out correct later.

Here is one possible version of the command you will use;

```
robocopy /copyall /mir /xj E:\Users D:\Users
```

To move \Users from Windows/SSD to HDD:

- /mir tells robocopy to mirror the directories, this will copy all
  files and permissions.
- /xj is very important, this tells robocopy not to follow junction points. If you forget this, you will have a lot of trouble.
- Be sure no files failed to copy (FAILED column = 0).

Then you must remove the old Users Folder from the Windows/SSD (c:) drive, before you can create the symlink:

Example:

```
rmdir /S /Q E:\Users
```

Create a NTFS Junction/symlink that points to the new Users folder:

Example:

```
mklink /J E:\Users D:\Users
```

> Use the /J switch to create a junction that's a hard symlink. (If you
>   use the /D switch, you'll also have to edit the registry, cuz it won't
>   be a hard link.) Using /J, when Windows looks for the C:\Users dir, it
>   will find it! But it will be on the HDD instead of the SSD. Tricky!
>
> To see the proof of what you've created, still in the command prompt
>   window, go into the actual Windows/SSD and do the "dir" command, and
>   you'll see: "Users [D:\Users]"
>
> Now restart and you'll see \Users on your HDD, and there you go. No
>   further configuration or fiddling required. New user profiles will all
>   be stored on the D: drive, as will any user specific data. And it is
>   achievable without any messing about in the registry, searching and
>   replacing values, or having to mess with new profiles in any way.
>   Totally set and forget.

**I should be clear here that Microsoft does not suggest moving the User Profile to another partition.**  **Please backup your data** before you follow this guide, **please read the article** so you **understand everything** about this guide, **before you follow it**.

I based on the following answer on this Lifehacker article:

[Source - Lifehacker - 2010](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7)